# Automatic restart after crash on Google Container Engine

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to figure out if my application process running on GKE will automatically restart in case of crash (f.e. on traditional setup I would create upstart script to handle that)?

Answer (score 0):

If your pod's [Restart Policy](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/pod-states/#restartpolicy) is `Always`, then it will be restarted by kubelet in case of crash.